# Can I connect a C wire to enable a furnace fan?

Tags: furnace, fans, cooling

Hot weather is here and we don't have AC in our rental house, but our thermostat does have the fan option. After searching online, and seeing other solutions, I decided to look into our setup.

All wires are properly connected to our Honeywell rth230b (4 wires). When I look in the furnace, they only have R and W connected, with the other wires just hanging out. If I was to get our fan working, should I just be connecting the C fan wire, or am I safe with connecting both G and C, without having an AC unit?

Comment: In a rental probably not.  Would be best to contact the landlord and they will probably need to have HVAC technician in to do the work.  Renters and landlords are very limited in what work they can do legally themselves.

Comment: Unless the furnace is down in a basement(cool), it might be cheaper just to use portable plug in fans, usually smaller motors using less power and can be placed where they do most good.

Comment: Even if it were legal for you to do the work, at a minimum, we'd need a picture of how the thermostat and furnace are connected. Just because there are conventions doesn't mean they're always followed. (Witness the myriad number of other questions here with wires used in unconventional color combinations.)

Comment: I normally put a blower override switch on the air handler itself. When in base housing we only had swamp coolers and adding a switch to the heaters air handler circulated the air cooling the upstairs quite well(make sure to turn the thermostat down) , as it is a rental I would check with the land lord prior to making any changes the low voltage side thermostat doesn't require licenses in most states but some you can’t even change a light switch without an electrical license.